# Artifacts related to the software side

Tags: ubuntu, drivers, pop-os, amd-graphics

[image]I started using Pop os(Ubuntu based), before that I used Windows. On linux there are artifacts, sometimes the screen starts blinking white, I don't understand what to do with them. Changing the resolution to a lower and scale helps to avoid for a while artifacts.Artifacts were on all distributions of Linux(Ubuntu,Arch,Fedora).. I will be very grateful if you can help me
Laptop: Redmibook 15 pro 2023
Kernel: 6.7.5-xanmode
OS: Pop!_OS 22.04
CPU:Ryzen 7 7840hs
GPU:Radeon 780m

My problem is in the video:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TC2pOlPQxO4

Answer (score 0):

AMD Ryzen 7 7840hs should work with the free software `radeon` provided by `xserver-xorg-video-ati` package. Or the proprietary driver from the [ofiicial website](https://www.amd.com/en/support/linux-drivers).

Comment: Thanks! I installed these drivers, hopefully everything will be ok, I'll give feedback later on

Answer (score 0):

I'd try using a mainline kernel instead of the xanmod kernel you have installed there. I don't recognise that one being provided with Pop!OS.

There's currently a lot of work being done on the amd-gpu firmware provided in the mainline kernel that may not be getting merged to xanmod's kernel for whatever reason.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the reply, this problem is also found in mainline, that's why I changed to xanmod.